# Match two strings with && but getting match on either/or

Tags: string, match

I'm trying to take a number of input strings and have a

```
do {
} while
```

loop matching the strings with

```
while (!sqlw.equals(w) && !sqlc.equals(c));
```

However this returns positive match if either one or the other is matched, rather than both. Any ideas? I guess it is something simple.

Comment: Can we see your inputs/outputs?

Comment: hi - so I set String sqlw = ""; and String sqlc =""; earlier in the script, then open a SQLdb and extract field1 and field 2 and assign these to the sqlw ad sqlc. earlier user input puts into "w" and "c" from action buttons..... then just try and find a match on W and C rather than W or C -- this is Java XML via Exclipse. so the while does stuff while these "w" and "c" do not match, then on match drops out the while loop to present the matched data.

Comment: Can we see the exact values that are not evaluating to your expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the thing is, in this line:

```
while (!sqlw.equals(w) && !sqlc.equals(c));
```

the expression becomes false if either sqlw.equals(w) is true (making !sqlw.equals(w) false) or !sqlc.equals(c) is true (making !sqlc.equals(c) false).

Try replacing && with || like so

```
while (!sqlw.equals(w) || !sqlc.equals(c));
```

That way, the expression is false only if !sqlw.equals(w) and !sqlc.equals(c) are both false (i.e. when both match).

EDIT: You could also change it to

```
while (!(sqlw.equals(w) && sqlc.equals(c)));
```

which does the same thing but is perhaps a little more faithful to what you wanted (loop while we haven't matched both).

Comment: Brilliant - knew it had to be something simple ---- thanks for everyone's help .... this fixed it....

Answer (score 0):

The equals method returns a boolean value. Try sqlw.equals('w') == false.

Also make sure your data types are the same in both cases. One might be a string and the other an array object of some sort.

Comment: is == rather for int and char rather than string ?

Comment: the sqlw.equals('w') does the actual comparison and returns a value of 0 or 1 (or true and false as you will). Therefore I'm comparing against the return value here.

Comment: the expanded code is String sqlcost = "";     String sqlweather = "";

Comment: @Nigelflegg

Yes, never use "==" for strings; always use .equals().

Comment: @Dennis The sqlw.equals('w') == false is only comparing the return value of .equals which will always be 0 or 1. I'm not comparing the string w to w here for example.

Comment: ah - now the cost line "c" is CharSequence from a spinObj .... so I guess I need to change the CharSquence to String first

Comment: You can probably cast to a string type.